# html can't click on checkboxes

Tags: html, css, asp.net

This is my html:

```
<div style="width: 45%; float: left; margin-left:5%">
                    <div class="chartHeaderClass" style="width: 100%;">
                        <h3>Service Level Per Campaign</h3>
                        <%-- Start Dropdown Code --%>
                        <a id="DropdownSeviceLink" href="#">+</a>
                        <div ID="campaignDiv" runat="server" ><ul>

                                              </ul>
                        </div>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/DropdownCheckbox.js"></script>
                        <%-- End Dropdown Code --%>
                    </div>
                    <div id="line-chart" class="chart-holder" style="border:1px solid #D5D5D5; margin-top:2px">
                        <canvas class="overlay" width="479" height="265"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 45%; float: right">
                    <div class="chartHeaderClass" style="width: 100%;">
                        <h3>Calls Per Campaign</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="pie-chart" class="chart-holder" style="border:1px solid #D5D5D5; margin-top:2px">
                        <canvas class="overlay" width="479" height="265"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

notice that it has this div `campaignDiv` which I fill in c# like this:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
                List<string> comps = getCompainNames();
                string html = "<ul>";
                for (int i = 0; i < comps.Count(); i++) {
                    html = html + CreateLiCheckbox(comps[i]);
                }
                html = html + "</ul>";
                campaignDiv.InnerHtml = html;
            }
private string CreateLiCheckbox(string checkBoxText)
        {
            return string.Format("<li><input type=\"checkbox\">{0}</li>", checkBoxText);
        }
```

This result is this:

[image]

I can't click on the checkboxes. In other words, when I click on them nothing happens

#### I noticed something

I can't select the text inside the red area. It seems that it is not exit because when I tried to select it using `the mouse`, nothing becomes selected.

could u help please?

#### css for this red area is

```
#DropdownSeviceLink {
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}
a#DropdownServiceLink:visited {
    color:inherit;
}
#campaignDiv {
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}
```

#### Finally the context of my page is

when clicking on that `plus` sign, I want to show this red area, I can do that on jquery, but I just told you the context maybe that helps

#### jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jdhMs/

Comment: The `checkBoxText` is not associated with the checkbox at all. You need to add a `<label>` tag, with a `for=` attribute that points to the `id` of the `checkbox`

Comment: @NickR why is that please? usually I add checkbox in html like this `<input type="checkbox" value="HTC" />` and it works

Comment: @NickR anyway, do u think that the checkboxes are not clickable because of that?

Comment: The actual checkbox should be clickable yes - but the text won't select the checkbox. Which one is easier/more accessible? - http://jsfiddle.net/VHMn5/

Comment: @NickR sorry I didn't understand you question . I edited ur jsfille and removed the `label` and I still can click . but in my case, I can't http://jsfiddle.net/VHMn5/1/

Comment: Can you add all your HTML and CSS to a JSFiddle - and see if you can still replicate the problem. Maybe there is something overlapping the checkboxes?

Comment: @NickR I gave you the best I can. the other css is for drawing charts. I really wish I could give you more. However, I can give you access through team viewer to my whole code if you want

Comment: That includes the code-behind stuff, I want to see what the final rendered html looks like, otherwise there's not that much that can be done to help.

Comment: @NickR Okay, I can give you the code of html that is rendered on the browser. and the css. is that okay? but I will do that after 2.5 hour . what do u think please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli The code as shown here should work. so the problem is probably somewhere else. You may have some other HTML elements that are not visible but that are in the same position on the screen, blocking access to the campaigndiv.

Comment: @NickR I edited the question and added a working code jsfiddle pleaes check

Comment: @MrLister I edited the question and gave you a jfiddle to the code please check.

Comment: I will catch you later guys after 2.5 hours, really apprecaite your help

Comment: It looks like your `<canvas>` element is sitting over the list items, you could add `.chartHeaderClass { position:relative; z-index:99999 }` as a quick fix.

Comment: @NickR write an answer to accept it pleaes

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same issue in my application and it turned out that the div I had my checkboxes in was being overlapped by the footer of the modal box. Since the footer of the modal box was white/transparent, this wasn't evident until I added a border around the footer. Only then I was able to see that I could see the checkboxes but couldn't actually select them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know its work or not but try Z-Index.

Example:

```
#campaignDiv {
   Z-Index:100;
}

li{
   Z-Index:101;
}
```

Comment: Z-index by itself doesn't do anything, so the one on the `li` is completely useless.

Comment: It worked for me. I've added z-index to parent div and able to click on checkbox.
Thank you.